# Documentation for Gradle tasks in Android Studio

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

The Gradle tasks pane on the right side of Android Studio has a long list of tasks as shown in the following screenshot.  Where can I find the documentation for them?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see the list of commands which can be executed from the current project, you can type `gradle -q tasks` in the console while being in the project directory. This command also has parameter `--all` which prints all available commands and more details on them: `gradle -q tasks --all`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.  When I do that, I get: 'gradle" is not recognized as an internal or external command.  I can do it with Gradlew. How can I get the details of one task (e.g. assembleRelease). I tried "gradlew help --task assembleRelease", but it does not give all the details of "--all".  It seems "--all" cannot be used with "help -task...".

Comment: '--all' option is used to show all available commands. When I run `gradle help --task :app:assembleRelease', I'm getting pretty much the same output I'm getting by `gradle -q tasks --all`, only it restricted by single command.

Comment: I gather there are no documents explaining these tasks. Where are they defined?  Can I view their scripts?